# how to retain state of listview during orientation changes?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, orientation-changes

Hello guys i know after reading the title of my question you find it very simple to answer but as i am new in android development so i find it hard to retain state of listview during orientation change and even of fragment state i surf a lot on google but i not find any satisfactory solution for retaing state during orientation change i know their is an onsaveinstancestate() method in which you have to put your each view data but i think that their is a better solution so please help me in finding the solution for it .You can also provide the link of good tutorials on orientation change..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: what state of listview?

Comment: Actually i want my whole listview will be retained like image nd text of all listview item and the selected item which is colored.

Comment: do you know about configChanges property?

Comment: firstly i want to thanks for reply and Yes Mr.Tarun Varshney i know about configchanges but according to best of my knowledge  it is depriciated by google .

Comment: It is not deprecated yet. but yes, use this as less as possible.

Comment: can you please tell how to detach fragment and save it state  and on activity recreation reattach fragment .It will be a great help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I've noticed that depending on your implementations, listview state is saved by default but to restore the state, recreate the listview and make sure one of the super methods with `savedInstanceState` as parameter is called afterwards (not before). Why? Since the listview state has been saved, the super method restores it and if you recreate after calling super, you override the restored state.
- Another method is to override `onSaveInstanceState(outState)` of the activity, put the listview state in the bundle,

  ```
  outState.putParcelable("listview.state", listview.onSaveInstanceState());
  ```

  Then when you override `onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)`, after recreating the listview, you call;

  ```
  Parcelable listViewState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("listview.state");
  listview.onRestoreInstanceState(listViewState);
  ```

Check for null values and good luck!

Comment: thank you very much for your valuable answer Olayinka i want to know with the help of putparcable can we put the complete layout in bundle and later on retrieve it after configration changes in oncreate or on .onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState) method .

Comment: @android_learner you can't do that. The layout is a heavy object to retain and it is not Parcelable

Comment: sir so it mean  if we have to retain state of layout then we have to individually save the state of each view and what  about fragment  how to retain state of fragment if we have to keep fragment in backtrack.

Comment: @android_learner Saving the state of a view in android involves saving the rendered data, like index, text, numbers, checked state, select list or what have you. You can't simply save the view because android redraws the view when the activity goes on or off screen, on configuration changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setRetainInstance(true); in fragment

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // find the retained fragment on activity restarts
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        dataFragment = (RetainedFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(“data”);

        // create the fragment and data the first time
        if (dataFragment == null) {
            // add the fragment
            dataFragment = new DataFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(dataFragment, “data”).commit();
            // load the data from the web

        }

        // the data is available in dataFragment.getData()
        ...
    }


}
```

Create your Listview inside fragment  - Fragment will be-

```
public class RetainedFragment extends Fragment {


    // this method is only called once for this fragment
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated");
 // retain this fragment
   setRetainInstance(true);
   // create your listview here


}

}
```

Comment: can u please tell what is MyDataObject  and DataFragment here and how you have find fragment by data tag .Please explain it in detail.Thank You

Comment: But what is DataFragment here and how you call fragment by tag data?

Comment: Sorry, that would be RetainFragment

Comment: thank you tarun for your responce but setretainstate only work with headlessfragment if i am having a new layout or backstable unable then it won't work can u please tell how to retain fragment when i have a different layout in both portrait and landscape mode.And if i have to call fragment by tag then how to give this fragment a tag name.?

Answer (score 0):

I would retain the state of the entire Activity by adding this line to the manifest, as a property inside the Activity tag:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: This is a bad solution and leads to lazy programming and difficult-to-maintain code. 

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Changing the device language or date format will no longer update your app's translation unless it's restarted. You won't be able to set landscape-specific layouts. You won't be able to change the app theme without a full restart. If the activity is killed because of low memory, your app will probably crash.
Don't do this.